# CollapsingToolbarLayout seems to prevents overscrolling effects on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

it seems, that CollapsingToolbarLayout within an AppBarLayout prevents RecyclerView to show overscrolling effects (top + bottom). Setting overscrollmode doesn't helped. The FrameLayout (has default behavior set) is replaced by a RecyclerView.

*XML-Layout 1:*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ... >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ...>
            <ImageView ... />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout ... />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything works fine as expected, except that no scrolling effects on the recycler are visible when I'm scrolling to the top or the end.

Layout 2 works and the overscrolling effects are visible.

*XML-Layout 2:*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ... >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ...>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Have anybody a solution for this behavior? Or what's wrong with my layouts?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using "NestedScrollView" for making collapsing toolbar?

Comment: No, I don't need a NestedScrollView.

Comment: What does this ' <FrameLayout ... />' contains?

Comment: This will be replaced by another Fragment containing a RecyclerView LinearLayout).

Another construct from XML-Layout 1, but with ViewPager (with more than one Fragment and RecyclerViews) instead of the FrameLayout doesn't show the overScroll either.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: No I didn't, sorry :(